# Angular is not defined Gulp.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

I still have this error Angular is not defined. Im 99.9999% Sure its something to do with the paths not being confugred properly, but im out of clue. I cant fix it! This is my folder structure as of now:

```
bower_components/
node_modules/
app/
   components/
              home/
                   controller/
                              homeCtrl.js
                   css/
                         home.css
                   home.html

    shared/
           css/
           directives/
           filters/
           directives/
           sass/
           services/
assets/
    audio/
    debug/
    dist/
         app.min.js
         vendor.min.js
    lib/
    etc...

gulp/
   paths.js

gulpfile.js
index.html
etc....
```

It for some reason says angular is not defined.

**Gulpfile.js:**

```
//Require Gulp
var gulp = require("gulp");
var ngAnnotate = require("gulp-ng-annotate");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var sourceMaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
var util = require('gulp-util');
var coffee = require("gulp-coffee")
var clean = require("gulp-clean");
var expect = require('gulp-expect-file');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var es = require('event-stream');
var ng_annotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate')


var base = 'app';
// var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');

var paths = require("./gulp/paths");

//remove temporary directories like dist
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/dist', {read: false})
    .pipe(clean());
});

// combines all js files into one and create sourcemaps for them
gulp.task('scripts', function(done) {
    gulp.src(paths.js)
    .pipe(sourceMaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', util.log))
    .pipe(sourceMaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest))
    .on('error', util.log)
    .on('end', done);
});



gulp.task('copy', function() {
  var files = ['bower_components/angular/angular.min.js'];
  return gulp.src(files)
    .pipe(expect(files))
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.js, ['scripts'])
});

gulp.task('scripts:vendor', function() {
   return gulp.src(paths.vendor_js)
        //  .pipe(concat(paths.vendor_js[0]))
         .pipe(concat('vendor.min.js'))
         .pipe(uglify().on('error', util.log))
         .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest));
});


gulp.task('serve', function() {

})


gulp.task('default', function() {
    console.log("running gulp");
});
```

**gulp/Paths.js:**

```
module.exports = {
    dest: 'assets/dist',
    js: [
        'app/app.module.js',
        'app/app.run.js',
        'app/shared/**/*.module.js',
        'app/shared/**/*.js',
        'app/components/**/*.js',
        'app/components/**/*.module.js'
    ],
    sass: ['app/shared/**/*.sass'],
    vendor_js: [
         'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
         'bower_components/angular/angular.min.js',
         'bower_components/**/*.min.js',
         'assets/lib/svg-assets-cache/svg-assets-cache.js',
         'assets/lib/alertifyjs/build/alertify.min.js',
         'assets/lib/Recaptcha/googleRecaptchaAPI.js',
         'assets/lib/angular-screenfull/angular-screenfull.min.js',
         'assets/lib/screenfull/screenfull.min.js',
         'assets/lib/angular-selectize/angular-selectize.js'
    ],
    vendor_styles: [
        'bower_components/selectize/dist/css/selectize.css',
        'bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'assets/lib/alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.css',
        'assets/lib/alertifyjs/build/css/themes/semantic.min.css',
        'bower_components/vex/css/vex.css',
        'bower_components/vex/css/vex-theme-flat-attack.css',
        'assets/lib/material-charts/material-charts.min.css'
    ]
};
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="html_container">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1200">
    <title>Ng-Forum</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/lib/alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/lib/alertifyjs/build/css/themes/semantic.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/vex/css/vex.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/vex/css/vex-theme-flat-attack.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/amanuel2/MathGame/master/chartjs/material-charts.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>

<body ng-app="ForumApp">
    <div ui-view></div>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javscript" src="assets/dist/vendor.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/dist/app.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Help would be greatly appreciated here! Btw im working it on Cloud9IDE So if we could fix it there, it would be quick and fantastic! https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/ng-fourm

Comment: I see your angularJS reference in HTML is commented, Remove the comment and try to run the code it should work.

Comment: Lol @shiva its commented. meaning it dosent matter. and matter of fact i already tried like that

Comment: Well, does your "bower_components/" folder has the angular files? as you are copying file from their so.  if not try "bower install" commond

Comment: @shiva yes look at my cloud9 there already is angular folder: https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/ng-fourm#openfile-README.md

Comment: You're using the ui-view directive but not including angular-ui-router

Comment: yea i am.. @jbrown its in paths.js . And thats not the problem lol.. its angular is not defined.. Gosh, is this an unsolvable problem?

Comment: lol as i see it now its not in paths.js but........ the problem is not ui-router, but angular is not defined @jbrown

Comment: im importing all  .min.js as you can see on third array element @jbrown go in cloud9 to help us: https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/ng-fourm#openfile-README.md

Comment: @Dsafds - the unsolvable part may be that you're asking us to look at code in Cloud9 IDE that requires login credentials rather than some public editor like plunker or jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

The reason was that i mispelled javascript:

```
<script type="text/javscript" src="assets/dist/vendor.min.js"></script>
```

It was preety hard to find because, something that simple can completely throw you off!